# Spring Security SAML signingKey/encryptionKey

Tags: spring, security, saml

> Comments in the source code:
>
> 1. encryptionKey: Encryption key used for encrypting messages send to the remote entity or decrypting data sent to the local one.
> 2. signingKey: Signing key used for signing messages or verifying signatures of this entity.

I saw the signingkey sign send message in the source code, but I didn't see the code for the verify signature.

```
if (sign) {
        Assert.notNull(samlContext.getLocalSigningCredential(), "Cannot sign outgoing message as no signing credential is set in the context");
        samlContext.setOutboundSAMLMessageSigningCredential(samlContext.getLocalSigningCredential());
    }
```

Usually signingKey/encryptionKey should be different between sp and idp.I can't understand the above explanation of these two fields. what are your suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encryption and signing are used to cover two different needs : 
the first one ensures you that only the receiver can read the content of the assertion while the second one ensures you that an assertion have been generated by the entity who has applied the signature and that it hasn't been modified.
Usually you should use encryption when you don't want the message to be read by none but the receiver (sensible data) and use signature when you want to be sure about the emitter, (almost always for authentication responses and attribute statements)

Encryption and signing are implemented on asymmetric cryptography.
That means you can use the public key to verify a signature or you can use it to encrypt a message so that it can only be decrypted by the owner of corrispondent private key.